# Connection error in ESP 8266 module (does not exist or your board is not connected)

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

I get the following error which I try to upload the code. I tried changing the upload speed and changing cable, nothing worked. Thanks in advance. cheers !!

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 921600"

Executable segment sizes:

IROM   : 248548          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR)

IRAM   : 27928   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...)

DATA   : 1312  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP

RODATA : 2220  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP

BSS    : 25568 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP

Sketch uses 280008 bytes (26%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.

Global variables use 29100 bytes (35%) of dynamic memory, leaving 52820 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

esptool.py v2.8

Serial port COM6

Connecting........

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Chathura\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 65, in

```
esptool.main(cmdline)
```

File "C:/Users/Chathura/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main

```
esp.connect(args.before)
```

File "C:/Users/Chathura/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 478, in connect

```
last_error = self._connect_attempt(mode=mode, esp32r0_delay=True)
```

File "C:/Users/Chathura/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 455, in _connect_attempt

```
self.sync()
```

File "C:/Users/Chathura/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 394, in sync

```
timeout=SYNC_TIMEOUT)
```

File "C:/Users/Chathura/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 337, in command

```
self.write(pkt)
```

File "C:/Users/Chathura/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 300, in write

```
self._port.write(buf)
```

File "C:/Users/Chathura/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 323, in write

```
raise writeTimeoutError
```

serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout

the selected serial port serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout

does not exist or your board is not connected

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: is the esp8266 in flashing mode?

Comment: Make sure your esp board in flashing mode. Also, try to press the reset button or EN button while the program is run. If there's no reset button on your board.

Comment: Flashing mode means, Pressing the flash button and run the program(upload)?